# How to refresh and add value a cell in Google sheet using Google Apps Script at same time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to input 2 values in 1 function. I can input first one without problem, the second one is being inputted based on the first value, so since both of them in same function the second one can't be inputted. I tried to use `flush()` method after I inputted first value, but the second value still cant find the first value.
Here's my code :

```
function addItem(e){
   var sheet =  ss.getSheetByName('items');
    var id = e.parameter.id; 
    var qty = e.parameter.qty;
    var lc = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var old_date = data.pop()[0];
    var new_date = e.parameter.date;
    if (old_date != new_date) sheet.appendRow([new_date]);
    
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    for (var i = 1; i <= lc; i++)  {
      for (var j = 1; j <= lr; j++) {
        var rid = sheet.getRange(1, i).getValue();
        var red = sheet.getRange(j,1).getValue();
        if (rid == id && red == new_date){
            sheet.getRange(j, i).setValue(qty);
        }}}}
```

My goal is to add string `new_date` by using `pop()[0]` and `appendRow`, wait for the data is inputted using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`, getting both Range and Value of `new_date`and `id` with increment checking all rows and column, so I can input `qty` based on `id` column and `new_date` row.

as you can see in the picture, the `new_date` 11/11/1111 is in (row 3, column 1) meanwhile the `id` 1 is in (row 1,column 2), and I need to input `qty` in (row 3 and column 2). the problem that I have is when the code is running, it can't detect the `new_date` that just being inputted, so the `qty` can't be inputted because it think that the `new_date` is not there.

[image: What I encounter]

Comment: I would have to see an image of the sheet in order to assist you.

Comment: @Cooper I edited it

Comment: I don't understand the image where is the id being stored?

Comment: @Copper `id` is just being checked not inputted, the only thing that inputted is just `date` and `qty`. so to input `qty` I need to check if its the right `id` and `date` or not.

Comment: @Cooper since `date` is being inputted at same time as `qty`, the `date` become blank instead of what I just inputted. I think it just because they are in same function.

Comment: I think one thing is that you cannot compare date objects you can only compare new Date().valueOf() or new Date().getTime().  Both return milliseconds and can be compared numerically.  At this point I still can't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi, as mentioned by @Cooper, your goal is not that clear. Based on your initial code you want to increment the quantity based on the number of duplicates having the same date and id. But what confuses me is your data itself, where an id was defined in row 1 and you have columns date, a, b and c in row 2. Please provide more details regarding what you want to do.

Comment: @Cooper I updated the code and adding my goal I try to accomplish, hope you understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just separate the function and it works perfectly.

```
function addDate(e){
    var sheet =  ss.getSheetByName('items');
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var old_date = data.pop()[0];
    var new_date = e.parameter.date;
    if (old_date != new_date) sheet.appendRow([new_date]);
}

function addItem(e){
    var sheet =  ss.getSheetByName('items');
    var sku = e.parameter.sku;
    var qty = e.parameter.qty;
    var date = e.parameter.date;
    var lc = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    for (var i = 1; i <= lc; i++)  {
        for (var j = 1; j <= lr; j++) {
            var rid = sheet.getRange(1, i).getValue();
            var red = sheet.getRange(j,1).getValue();
            if (rid == sku && red == date){
                sheet.getRange(j, i).setValue(qty);
                var result = "Input Succeed";
            }
        }
    }
}
```